Analytical transformation or an effective numerical method for calculating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{K_0(\frac{n}{a})\sin(n)}$ series
I have a series for that I need to get a fast calculation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}K_0\!\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)\sin(n)$$
where $K_0$ is the $0^{\text{th}}$ modified Bessel functions of the second kind, and $a$ is some constant.
This series converges extremely slowly for large values of $a$.
Is there any analytical transformation of this series that would allow us to get a faster solution?
Or if there is no such solution, maybe there are some methods of accelerating convergence that will suit this type of function?

The integral form $$
\frac{{\sin (1)}}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\cosh ((1/a)\cosh t) - \cos (1)}}}
$$ has better convergence properties.

Thank you, it's a really great solution for my case! I have several other similar functions like $K_0(\frac{n}{a})\cos(n)$ or $K_0(\frac{n}{a})\sin(an)\cos(bn)$ or etc. Can I get an integral forms for similar cases using some method? Can you share a link to the relevant source of the theory

@gearquicker: How did this series arise?

@Gary I saw your response, but the joke went over my head.

@A rural reader This series is a part of complex equation for flows in porous media. I try to compute it in adequate time. The develop of this equation is so complex for me, so I can't explain how this series is arisen. The only thing I can do is a post a link to the original article where it's arisen, if you need to.

Utilising the integral representation $K_{0}(z) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\rm e}^{-z \cosh t} {\rm d}t$, we can rewrite the series as
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {K_0 (\alpha n)\sin (\beta n + \gamma )}&  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \alpha n\cosh t} {\rm d}t} \operatorname{Im} {\rm e}^{(\beta n + \gamma ){\rm i}} } 
\\ & = \operatorname{Im} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{\gamma {\rm i}} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{( - \alpha \cosh t + \beta {\rm i})n} } {\rm d}t} \\ & = \operatorname{Im} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \alpha \cosh t} {\rm e}^{(\beta  + \gamma ){\rm i}} }}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - \alpha \cosh t + \beta {\rm i}} }}{\rm d}t} 
\\ & = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm sin}(\beta  + \gamma ) - {\rm e}^{ - \alpha \cosh t} \sin \gamma }}{{\cosh (\alpha \cosh t) - \cos \beta }}{\rm d}t} 
\end{align*}
provided $\alpha>0$, and $\beta$, $\gamma \in \mathbb R$. Due to the double-exponential nature of the integrand, this representation has better convergence properties.
You can use identities like $\cos (an) = \sin \left( {an + \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)$ and $2\sin (an)\cos (bn) = \sin ((a - b)n) + \sin ((a + b)n)$ to handle your more general sums.

@Gray Thank you very much for your solution and for this clear explanation! This completely solved my problem!
